# Using opencv with C++ .net application compilation issues

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, opencv

I didn't face any issues while linking opencv library with basic console application but when I moved to do the same in a .net framework template I got many LNK errors:

[image: LNK errors]

I didn't do anything strange except that I included the include and using namespace only.

I appreciate any assistance provided

PS: I managed to run it if I install the opencv package via NuGet but I don't wan't to use NuGet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of opencv are you using, and visual studio?
did you include additional libraries and headers to your project?
and did you add the bin path of opencv to your environment variables?

Comment: I'm using opencv 3.10 + vs2015 comminity and I already added the include additional libraries as well as the linker directories and names of dependencies and it didn't work

Comment: did you use  "E:/OpenCv/build/x64/vc14/lib/opencv_world310d.lib" for your library and "E:/OpenCv/build/include" for your include path?

Comment: Yes I did that and that's why I'm going crazy. I did everything I googled for and no luck.
I even created a new solution and it didn't work for me. Same LNK errors.

Comment: can you take a screen grab of your include path and library path? are you using 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: I changed my project to x64 and added the directories and I got only one error now which is:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK1561 entry point must be defined VisionApp01 D:\D_Drive\Sources\OpenCV\VisionApp01\VisionApp01\LINK 1

Comment: I changed: void Main(array<String^>^ args), into: void main(), then I got an error about: opencv_world310d.dll is not found. So I copied the file into my project and now it is working. But I have the Main form opening as well as a console. How to remove the console and keep the .net Form?

Comment: I think I'm done!
I had to set the linker->System->SubSystem to WINDOWS. Then I had to go to Advanced->Entry Point to Main